# Mute AVAudioPlayer Background music with UISwitch

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer, uiswitch, mute

I am very new to programming and I am just working on my first app. I haven't been able to find an answer to this for weeks. I would really appreciate some help.

I have background music through AVAudioPlayer (the only sound in my app) that begins playing when my app opens - here is the code in my appdelegate.m:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    NSString *bgmusic=[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"cloud_two-full-" ofType:@"mp3"];
    bgmusic1=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:bgmusic] error:NULL];
    bgmusic1.delegate=self;
    bgmusic1.numberOfLoops=-1;

    [bgmusic1 play];
    [bgmusic1 setVolume:1.0];
}
```

So, I've created a uiswitch that I want to use to be able to mute the background music. Here is the IBAction in my viewcontroller.m:

```
- (IBAction)speakerOnOff:(id)sender {
    static BOOL muted = NO;

    if (muted) {
        [bgmusic1 setVolume:1.0];
    } else {
        [bgmusic1 setVolume:0.0];
    }
    muted = !muted;
}
```

But when I click the switch to off the music continues to play at its normal volume. I only have 1 view controller. Please help! I just want the music to mute when the switch is clicked to off and then back to volume 1.0 when the switch is back on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write this code

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient error: nil];
```

above

```
bgmusic1=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:bgmusic] error:NULL];
```

and make your button action like this

```
- (IBAction)speakerOnOff:(id)sender {
    if ( bgmusic1.volume == 0) {
        bgmusic1.volume = 1;
    } else {
        bgmusic1.volume =0;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. I put that code in and ran the simulator. The background music is still not muting... Is there something else I could be doing wrong?

Comment: Also, when I created '- (IBAction)speakerOnOff:(id)sender' for "Event" I chose "Value Changed" is that the correct selection?

Comment: Make the buttons' send event Touch Up Inside

Comment: Add a breakpoint to check whether the code is executing or not.

Comment: I'm using a UISwitch not a button, would that make any difference?

Comment: When I use the breakpoint I'm getting a Thread 1: breakpoint 2.1 on          'if (muted) {

Comment: Edited the answer, check

Comment: Still not muting, does it have something to do with the code in the AppDelegate.m? Can we chat? or Skype chat?